# I'm trying to install winrandom using pip, but I keep getting an error

Tags: python, gcc, import, command

I'm using the command prompt to install winrandom:

C:\ python -m pip install winrandom

And I get the following message:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
---------------------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for winrandom
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and a solution to fix it?

Comment: Gcc is a compiler to compile C files to executables and libraries. It is either not installed on your system or the PATH environment variable is not referring to a directory with a gcc.exe inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, using Python 2.7, install it using the [executables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/winrandom/1.2).